# Webscraping for the Hidden Fields

Tags: python, web-scraping, hidden-field

I am web scraping a website: https://apps.ktrade.pk/webterminalv3/SignIn I can fetch HTML from it, but a div with class box-user-id's child elements are not appearing in my scraped html elements; while on inspection element, child elements of box-user-id's are showing.

I have tried it with multiple libraries like selenium, BeautifulSoup, mechanicalsoup etc. Please tell me how can I do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you actually trying to scrape? Are you trying to automate logging in?

Comment: Yes. And after logging, I want to scrape some data from that website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try that code to login

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session = requests.Session()

# get auth page
auth = session.get('https://apps.ktrade.pk/webterminalv3/SignIn')

# collect csrf token
soup = BeautifulSoup(auth.text, 'html.parser')
csrf_token = soup.find('input', {'name': 'csrfPreventionSalt'})['value']

# create login request
session.post('https://apps.ktrade.pk/webterminalv3/ajax/login', data={
    'username': 'your_username', 'password': 'your_password',
    'csrfPreventionSalt': csrf_token, 'actBrandName': 'KTrade'
})
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I am logging in and scraping data :)

Comment: @NaimaUrooj mark answer as correct please if you can

Comment: OK.
Can you please tell me from where did u find this thing?

session.post('https://apps.ktrade.pk/webterminalv3/ajax/login', data={
    'username': 'your_username', 'password': 'your_password',
    'csrfPreventionSalt': csrf_token, 'actBrandName': 'KTrade'
})

Comment: @NaimaUrooj in devtool. You can check on screen - https://ibb.co/QC0f7pd